# Python tkinter Mac and windows

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I want to make a desktop app obiously im a begginer so

if i built a gui in mac using python and tkinter that program will work on windows?

Also is tkinter the best framework?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, but tkinter applications will look different on different platforms. This means that you may get different buttons on Windows 7 vs MacOS X -- Tkinter is just using whatever the OS gives it.

As for it being the best framework, I couldn't say if it is the best or not, but it is pretty simple and works well. I normally use tkinter.